# Disable/Destroy dropzone after successful upload

Tags: dropzone.js

Is there a way to destroy or disable dropzone after the file uploads. I'm currently having an issue where the user can still drag and drop even after they have uploaded their file. I can't seem to find anything in their documentation. https://www.dropzonejs.com/

I've tried dropzone.off(); and dropzone.destroy() with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is [`.disable()`](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods)

Here an example:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

    // other options

    init: function() {

        let mydropzone = this; // closure

        this.on('success', function(file, response){

            mydropzone.disable();
        });
    }
};
```